# Algorithm that works like Unix Sort

Tags: algorithm, unix, sorting, file-io

for example our input file **in.txt**:

```
naturalistic 10
coppering 20
artless 30
```

after command: **sort in.txt**

```
artless 30
coppering 20
naturalistic 10
```

after command: **sort -n -k 2 in.txt**

```
naturalistic 10
coppering 20
artless 30
```

My Question: How can I manage keeping the lines stable while sorting according to column.
I want to whole line stays same while its order in general is changing?
What algoritm or code piece is useful? Is it about file reading or sorting facility?

Answer (score 2):

Standard UNIX `sort` doesn't document which algorithm it uses. It may even choose a different algorithm depending on such things as the size of the input or the sort options.

The [Wikipedia page on sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) lists many sorting algorithms you can choose from.

If you want a stable sort, there are plenty of options (the comparison table on the same Wikipedia page lists which ones are stable), but in fact any sorting algorithm can be made stable by tagging each data item with its original position in the input and breaking ties in the key comparison function according to that position.

Other than that, it's not exactly clear what you're asking. In your question you demonstrate the use of `sort` with and without `-n` and `-k` options, but it's not clear why this should influence the actual choice of sort algorithm...

Comment: +1 for a sympathetic yet informative and helpful answer. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a hash table of the strings with the num as key and string as value (I'm assuming they are unique) and then for the command `sort` , I'd sort based on values and for `-n -k 2` I'd sort based on keys. 
The POSIX standard does not dictate which algo to use, so different unix flavours may use different algos. GNU sort uses Merge Sort  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort